# SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:"

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run migrations rails:db:migrate, but i keep getting this error:

Caused by: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: buyers

This is the migration which causes the error, because i deleted Buyer Table before:

```
class AddUserToBuyers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
   add_reference :buyers, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

How can i delete this migration file now that Buyer Table doesn't exist anymore? So i will be able to run my new migrations.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i was able to solve this by running:

```
    rails db:reset
```

Deleted the migrations files referencing buyer table .
then do:

```
    rails db:migrate
```

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.